# Text variable not carrying over to IF statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am wondering why my completeText variable would not carry into the IF statements I am using for GUI Labels that appear as the user hovers over different models. I have succeeded in importing the text using a StreamReader but when I put:

```
            GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), completeText);
```

Into the IF statement nothing appears. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class OnClick : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool isClicked = false;
        string cdrw = "CD-RW";
        string powerSupply = "Power Supply";
        string hardDriveName = "Hard Drive";
        string crosspeiceName = "Crosspeice";
        string fanName = "Fan";
        string graphicsName = "Graphics Card";
        string ramName = "Ram";
        public string txt;
        public string completeText = "";
        public GameObject cdrwModel;
        public GameObject powerSupplyModel;
        public GameObject hardDriveModel;
        public GameObject crosspeiceModel;
        public GameObject fanModel;
        public GameObject graphicsModel;
        public GameObject ramModel;
        public GUI toogle;
        GUIStyle biggerFont;

        public void Start()
        {
            StreamReader reader = null;
            FileInfo theSourceFile = null;
            theSourceFile = new FileInfo(Application.dataPath + "/puzzles.txt");
            if (theSourceFile != null && theSourceFile.Exists)
                reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
            if (reader == null)
            {
            Debug.Log("puzzles.txt not found or not readable");
            }
            else
            {
                // Read each line from the file
                while ((txt = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(KillOnAnimationEnd(1f));
                    Debug.Log("-->" + txt);
                    completeText += txt;
                }
            }
            if (gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>() == null)
                gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(BoxCollider));
          biggerFont.fontSize = 40;
       }
      public void OnMouseEnter()
        {
            isClicked = true;
            completeText += txt;
        }

        public void OnMouseExit()
        {
            isClicked = false;
            completeText += txt;
        }

        public void OnGUI()
        {
        if ((isClicked) && (cdrwModel))
            {
         GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(5, 5, 400, 400), "<color=cyan><size=30>This is the </size></color>" + "<color=cyan><size=30>" + this.cdrw + "</size></color>");
                GUI.Label(new Rect(15, 35, 400, 400), "Press <TAB> for more information");
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))
                {
   GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
                    GUI.Box(new Rect(1000, 5, 400, 400), "What You Should Know");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(1135, 5, 400, 400), "___________________");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(1145, 23, 400, 400), "<color=red><size=20>The </size></color>" + "<color=red><size=20>" + this.cdrw + "</size></color>");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(15, 35, 400, 400), "Press <TAB> for more information");
                    GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), completeText);
     }
            }
    else if ((isClicked) && (powerSupplyModel))
            {
                GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(5, 5, 400, 400), "<color=cyan><size=30>This is the </size></color>" + "<color=cyan><size=30>" + this.powerSupply + "</size></color>");
                GUI.Label(new Rect(15, 35, 400, 400), "Press <TAB> for more information");
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))
                {
                    GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
                    GUI.Box(new Rect(1000, 5, 400, 400), "What You Should Know");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(1135, 5, 400, 400), "___________________");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(1145, 23, 400, 400), "<color=red><size=20>The </size></color>" + "<color=red><size=20>" + this.powerSupply + "</size></color>");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(15, 35, 400, 400), "Press <TAB> for more information");

                }
            }
```

Comment: Where is your class definition?  What context is completeTxt defined?

Comment: You can't define a function inside of a function.  The code you provided won't even *compile*.  So "nothing appears" is hardly a description of the problem...

Comment: Thanks for replying, Sorry I added the full code now - including just two if statements for the models

Comment: Please remove the extra consecutive blank lines when posting code here. It really hurts readability (too much scrolling to see your code).

Comment: ok - better code - now - which 'if' do you have an issue with?

Comment: @Jaindreas: When you debug this, where *specifically* is it failing?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  Where did those values come from?

Comment: Thanks for all your advice, Basically it works when I take it outside the parenthesis of the if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab)) but once they are added inside it no picks up the completeText variable as it doesn't appear at runtime.

Comment: I need to learn not to get burnt with incomplete code...

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), completeText);
```

does not bind the completeText variable to the Label.  It merely copies the value in completeText into the label.

Further changes to completeText will not effect what the Label displays.

Comment: that line is written in the `public void OnGUI()` function, which gets ran on every  single UI frame. So it will update even without a bind.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, What would you suggest I do or research to make sure it appears?